# Return Highcharts using Ajax and Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to return a highchart using AJAX from python bottle web service. 
The code for the web service:

```
app.get('/getmyname/<jsonstring>')
def getmyname(db, jsonstring):

ret = """{
            "chart": {
                "type": "column"
            },
            "colors": [
                    "#00B7DE"
                    "#00539E"
                    ],
            "title": {
                "text": "SALES - VOLUME"
            },
            "xAxis": {
                "categories": [w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w],
                "tickLength": "0"
            },

            "yAxis": {
                "gridLineWidth": 0,
                "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "title": {
                    "text": "K UNITS"
                },
                "labels": {
                    "enabled": false
                },

                "stackLabels": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "style": {
                        "fontWeight": "bold",
                        "color": "(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'"
                    }
                }
            },
            "credits": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "legend": {
                "align": "right",
                "x": "-30",
                "verticalAlign": "top",
                "y": "25",
                "floating": true,
                "backgroundColor": "(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white'",
                "borderColor": "#CCC",
                "borderWidth": "1",
                "shadow": true,
            },
            "tooltip": {
                "formatter": function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            "plotOptions": {
                "column": {
                    "stacking": "normal",
                    "dataLabels": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "color": "(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'",
                        "style": {
                            "textShadow": "0 0 3px black"
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            "series": [{
                "name": "EST",
                "data": [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 6, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4],                
            }, {
                "name": "VOD",
                "data": [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 6, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4]
            }]
        }"""; 

return json.dumps(ret)
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/getmyname/Query",
        data: JSON.stringify(output),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data){
                                alert(data) ;
                                $('#container').highcharts(data);
                                },
        error: function() {
                            alert("Something is not OK")    
                                },

        });
```

Though I can see the returned success alert(due to which I assume the Ajax call has returned  required the data), the chart doesnot get populated. Not sure where I am going wrong. It would be great if somebody could point out the error.

Comment: firstly, the attribute `tooltip.formatter` is a function, which makes it an invalid json. Also try pasting your JSON data to http://jsonblob.com/. You will see that there are few invalid strings

Comment: Tried enclosing the function in a variable, doesnt help as well.

Comment: JSON can't contain functions - remove them. Your `categories` are wrong. Your `colors` options won't work at all (probably black colors will be used). Also, don't forget to copy&paste errors from the javascript console.

Comment: @PawełFus   Changed the categories(I assume you were pointing out the extra 'w'). Removed the function and the colors as well, still no go. The problem is there is no error in the javascript console and I dont understand why.

Comment: Make sure you have div with `id="container"`. With categories I mean `categories: [w, w, w, ... ,w ]` is wrong. Should be: `categories: ["w", "w", "w", ... ,"w" ]`.

Comment: @PawełFus Oops facepalm!!, did not see that. After making the necessary changes the chart still didnot populate. I changed the `json.dumps` method to `json.loads` and the chart populated. Not sure what difference does this make. I use python 2.7.8, this matters maybe?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not Python guy. Maybe 2.7.8 version is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how but changing the return method helped and also the some changes with the JSON format. Every `(, ' "")` matters. The corrected code is bleow:

```
@app.get('/getmyname/<jsonstring>')
def getmyname(db, jsonstring):


ret = """{
    "chart": {
        "type": "column"
        },
    "colors": [
            "#00B7DE",
            "#00539E"
            ],
    "title": {
        "text": "SALES - VOLUME"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": ["Avg", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
        "tickLength": 0
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "K EURO"
        },
        "labels": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "stackLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "style": {
                "fontWeight": "bold",
                "color": "gray"
            }

        }
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },

    "legend": {
        "align": "right",
        "x": -30,
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "y": 25,
        "floating": true,
        "backgroundColor": "white",
        "borderColor": "#CCC",
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "shadow": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "normal",
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": true,
                "color": "white",
                "style": {
                    "textShadow": "0 0 3px black"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "EST",
        "data": [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 2]
    }, {
        "name": "VOD",
        "data": [2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 4, 5]
    }]
    }"""   

return json.loads(ret)
```

EDIT: I found this tool very helpful to debug JSON Format [JSONFormtter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)